# Azure Devops Release Pipeline select latest merged branche

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using Azure DevOps with an self-hosted-agents on different on-premise servers to manage the deployments.

For the versioning of of the releases of the (non Azure) Development tool I am using git commands to create branches and publish those branches to the Azure Repo.

The build DevOps pipeline is running without errors and creating and publish the artifact.

From the main branch repository, I have the following structure:

```
.
└── Releases/
    ├── Release A (coming from branch A)/
    │   └── *.WFT
    ├── Release B (coming from branch B)/
    │   └── *.WFT
    └── Release C (coming from branch C)/
        └── *.WFT
```

The release must only select the latest published branch in the release folder. How can I select with PowerShell in Azure DevOps Release Pipeline the latest branch sub folder (in this case `Release C`)?

Many thanks